# View only products without pricing

Tags: orocrm, orocommerce

i am trying to make the Non-Authenticated Visitors to see only the products!
i have done some steps that are on the oro docs, but on my storefront i still see the "price not vailable" and the qty per item! Is it possible to delete the pricing label's ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the block with prices is rendered by a **oro_product_price** import file so you have to update it in your theme.

1. Create in your theme  folder in **CUSTOM_BUNDLE/Resources/views/layouts/MY_THEME/imports** if it is not exist;
2. Then created a folder **oro_product_price** and put there a file **oro_product_price.yml**;
3. Add a visible option for **__product_price_container** block;

```yaml
layout:
    actions:
        -  '@setOption':
              id: __product_price_container
              optionName: visible
              optionValue: '=context["is_logged_in"]'
```

4. Update cache;

As an example have a look how it has done for **oro_product_grid** in Oro [custom theme](https://github.com/oroinc/orocommerce/tree/master/src/Oro/Bundle/CustomThemeBundle/Resources/views/layouts/custom/imports).